# I am getting this error that " building has encountered an error. The error occured during build"

Tags: eclipse, popupwindow

I simplied started a new project to learn about graphics and a class. immediately I clicked on ok, there was immediately a popup telling me that"building has encountered an error. The error occured during build" I have searched the forum and have not seen this answered previously. Please come to my aid

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: so, the screen shot that I provided is the only screen shout that it generated. I had reached the point of codes before the error occured. so, this is what I did

Comment: reached the point of codes before the error occured. so, this is what I did. [1] I clicked on file>new>java project [2]clicked next then finish and the error occured. I just generated the attached screenshot. I would like to add a new screenshot but I don't know how.